# NServiceBus.Host.exe as windows service log4net issue

Tags: windows-services, log4net, nservicebus

I use NServiceBus 2.6.

I use a log4net.config file & initialize logging facilities by code in my endpoint:

```
SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(() => 
       XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("log4net.config")));
```

When I run NServiceBus.Host.exe normally it logs well, but when I deploy it as a windows service using /install, nothing is logged anymore.

It works if I use the code based way:

```
SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net<RollingFileAppender>(...)
```

Any ideas why...?

Comment: Does the account that is running the service have the proper permissions on that file?  Also where is that code implemented exactly(what interface are you implementing)?

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry for the delay I was Off. As I said below, simply adding "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" works fine.
Anyway, it appears that my sample logged without that trick in Debug but not in Release. 
I will restart from scratch with a simplier endpoint to identify what works and what doesn't and I will repost after that.
Anyway thank you for your interest & continue your excelllent blog !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a process as a windows service, it will not by default set the current directory to the place where your binaries are located. This means that when you look for "log4net.config" it will actually search in c:\windows\system32.

Try this (before SetLoggingLibrary is called):

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

or, modify your code to something like this:

```
SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(() => 
   XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "log4net.config"))));
```